# Elementary Os 7 Horus Disable Animations

Tags: desktop, pantheon, horus

How i can Disable Animations in Elementary Os Pantheon

Answer (score 2):

There are several Gala options regarding animation, but mind you I haven't tested any of them.

I prefer to use dconf-editor. You can install it with `sudo apt install dconf-editor` and navigate to org -> pantheon -> desktop -> gala -> animations.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]